# Android TabWidget default style

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

I have a problem that sounds like this:
I have a TabHost and I want to change it's size (height and width) so I used inflate to do this

```
TextView tabContent = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_content,tab.getTabWidget(),false);
```

and my xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab_label"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:background="@color/green"
```

/>

This is working, but the problem is:
How do I inherit the old style of the tab since this is canceling it.
I mean i want this to be on the grey background and if i click it, to take focus and be yellow and so on, like the default tabs?

Thanks 
Arkde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you coose to customize your tabs, the standard tab behaviour is not accessible anymore.

Here is a very good example about customizing Tabs:

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136